# can anyone provide linq query

Tags: c#, linq

now I want a LINQ query like follows
if `compIds` are 0001 or 0002 then I can check condition with `divisionCode` 
if it `compIds` are 0005 or 0006 then no need to check with `divisionCode` so can anyone provide suggetion `compId` may increase depends on requirement

```
string[] compID = new string[] { "0002", "0001", "0005", "0006" };
string[] divisionCode = new string[] { "01021159", "02013350", "02013483", "02013804", "02013375", "02013374", "02013380", "02013398", "02017379", "02013391", "02013444", "02013353", "02004458", "02013394" };
var ACM = (from t1 in Entity.ApprovedContracts
          join t2 in Entity.ApprovedResources
          on t1.ApprovedResourceId equals t2.ResourceGeneralId
          where compID.Contains(t1.OpuCode) && divisionCode.Contains(t1.DivisionCode)
          select new
          {
                t1.OpuCode,
                t1.DivisionCode,
                t2.EnterpriseId,
                t2.ResourceEmail
          }).ToList();here
```

Comment: is there any patter in compId that we should check for deciding whether to check for divisionCode ? and what to check for divisionCode ? you question is not providing good information to help us to help you

Comment: and also what is wrong in your provided linq

Answer (score 0):

I think just need to add some more condition... should be something like this...

```
string[] compID = new string[] { "0002", "0001", "0005", "0006" };
string[] divisionCode = new string[] { "01021159", "02013350", "02013483", "02013804", "02013375", "02013374", "02013380", "02013398", "02017379", "02013391", "02013444", "02013353", "02004458", "02013394" };
var ACM = (from t1 in Entity.ApprovedContracts
      join t2 in Entity.ApprovedResources
      on t1.ApprovedResourceId equals t2.ResourceGeneralId
      where compID.Contains(t1.OpuCode) && (t1.OpuCode == "0005" || t1.OpuCode == "0006" || divisionCode.Contains(t1.DivisionCode)
      select new
      {
            t1.OpuCode,
            t1.DivisionCode,
            t2.EnterpriseId,
            t2.ResourceEmail
      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LINQ like this:

```
var orderDates = t1
                .Join(t2, _t1 => _t1.Id, _t2 => _t2.Id, (p, o) => new { 
                t1.OpuCode,
                t1.DivisionCode,
                t2.EnterpriseId,
                t2.ResourceEmail })
                .Where(r => r.compID.Contains(t1.OpuCode) >= startDate && r.divisionCode.Contains(t1.DivisionCode)).OrderBy(r => r.OrderDate);
```